# How to organize multiple types of user data?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm trying to figure out how to organize multiple kinds of user data in a database.

For example, the user is gathering multiple items in his cart. The items themselves are in a table which is different then the table of users. This user also have various preferences about the size measurements, favourite colors, favourite brands. What I'm trying to understand is how to have this data organized correctly, because it seems multiple columns is not the smart way.

```
User 1:
  Favorite brands: [x, y, z]
  Favorite colors: [black, green, blue]
  Size measurements: [pants: M, shirts: L]
  Items in cart: [item_1, item_2, item_3].
User 2:
  Favorite brands: [x, y]
  Favorite colors: [black, green, blue, purple]
  Size measurements: [pants: M, shirts: M]
  Items in cart: [item_3, item_2, item_6].
```

When I'm trying to figure out how to organize this, it seems multiple columns in the user table is not enabling me to have the right organization of the data. Pulling out different columns will put much pressure on the server, since many requests are being sent over and over again all the time the user is using the website.
I'm trying to understand whether there's a way to organize this data over files that will be stored on the server and will contain all the data users have submitted. Then, the local version of the site will be able to gather what data she needs when user is logging in and "downloads the file", leaving the server with less traffic.

Comment: It will be worth your time to read about entity-relationship database design.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the cart.

You need a `cart` table with columns like these

```
   cart_id   primary key 
   user_id   identify the user
   quantity  the number of items 
   sku       the sku (item stock-keeping-unit number, UPC barcode) in the cart
```

So, rows might look like this.

```
 cart_id    user_id    quantity   sku
    104      16654        1       2345623456
    105      16654        2       1234545678
```

In this table you may also need other information necessary to uniquely identify the item, like size and color.   You may also want unit price and price  x quantity.

As for the attributes of each user (favorites, measurements) you probably want an attribute table that looks something like this

```
    attribute_id    user_id     name            value
         2234       16654       BrandFavorite   Levis
         2235       16654       BrandFavorite   Vans
         2236       16654       ShirtSize       M
         2237       16654       PantsSize       M
```

That way you don't have to make a new table when your merchandisers dream up some new user attribute.

Read about entity-relationship database design and about normalization before you proceed with this design. Please.